# Can I get the result of domxpath nested classes into an array with keys => value?

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

I'm getting some data from a webpage for clients and that works fine, it gets all data in seperate rows by exploding the \n into new lines which I then map to specific array data to fill form fields with. Like so for each needed value:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $html);
$data['vraagprijs']         = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $lines[5]);
```

However, the data i need may be in Line 10 today, but might very well be line 11 tomorrow. So I'd like to get the values into named arrays. A sample of the HTML on the URL is as follows:

```
<div class="item_list">             
<span class="item first status">
    <span class="itemName">Status</span>                        
    <span class="itemValue">Sold</span>
</span>
<span class="item price">
    <span class="itemName">Vraagprijs</span>
    <span class="itemValue">389.000</span>
</span>
<span class="item condition">
    <span class="itemName">Aanvaarding</span>
    <span class="itemValue">In overleg</span>
</span>
...
</div>
```

This is my function model:

```
$tagName3   = 'div';
$attrName3  = 'class';
$attrValue3 = 'item_list';
$html       = getShortTags($tagName3, $attrName3, $attrValue3, $url); 

function getShortTags($tagName, $attrName, $attrValue, $url = "", $exclAttrValue = 'itemTitle') {

    $dom = $this->getDom($url);

    $html                 = '';
    $domxpath             = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $newDom               = new \DOMDocument;
    $newDom->formatOutput = true;

    $filtered = $domxpath->query(" //" . $tagName . "[@" . $attrName . "='" . $attrValue . "']/descendant::text()[not(parent::span/@" . $attrName . "='" . $exclAttrValue . "')] ");
    $i        = 0;
    while ($myItem   = $filtered->item($i++)) {
        $node   = $newDom->importNode($myItem, true);
        $newDom->appendChild($node); 
    }
    $html = $newDom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
```

What am I getting?

```
Status\nSold\nVraagprijs\n389.000\nIn overleg\n....
```

Desired output anything like:

```
$html = array("Status" => "Sold", "Vraagprijs" => "389.000", "Aanvaarding" => "In overleg", ...)
```

Is there a way to "loop" through the itemList and get each itemName and itemValue into an associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your happy with what the `getShortTags()` method does (or if it's used elsewhere and so difficult to tweak), then you can process the return value.

This code first uses `explode()` to split the output by line, uses `array_map()` and `trim()` to remove any spaces etc., then passes the result through `array_filter()` to remove blank lines.  This will leave the data in pairs, so an easy way is to use `array_chunk()` to extract the pairs and then `foreach()` over the pairs with the first as the key and the second as the value...

```
$html = getShortTags($tagName3, $attrName3, $attrValue3, $url);
$lines = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode(PHP_EOL, $html)));
$pairs = array_chunk($lines, 2);
$output = [];
foreach ( $pairs as $pair ) {
    $output[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
print_r($output);
```

with the sample data gives..

```
Array
(
    [Status] => Sold
    [Vraagprijs] => 389.000
    [Aanvaarding] => In overleg
)
```

To use this directly in the document and without making any assumptions (although if you don't have a name for several values, then not sure what you will end up with).  This just looks specifically for the base element and then loops over the `<span>` elements.  Each time within this it will look for the `itemName` and `itemValue` class attributes and get the value from these...

```
$output = [];
$filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='item_list']/span");
foreach ( $filtered as $myItem )  {
    $name= $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='itemName'])", $myItem);
    $value= $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='itemValue'])", $myItem);
    $output[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: That might work, I'll test later. However, sometimes there's not a combo of two (a pair), which is why i wondered if i could match on the itemNAme and itemValue. Will check first though. Thanks.

Comment: I've added some new code which just uses specific XPath for the pairs of data.

Comment: That works great Nigel. I'll need to make some adjustments but it is nicely put in my json format now so I'll get it to work eventually. Thanks!